# powerBi, Split the column to separate columns in order

Tags: powerbi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIjAy.png)

Please help in getting the column splitted in the required format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a new column, when in Powerbi *right click table, select New column* add 3 new columns

```
A= if(CONTAINSSTRING([projects],"A"),1,0)

B= if(CONTAINSSTRING([projects],"B"),1,0)

C= if(CONTAINSSTRING([projects],"C"),1,0)
```